# Why after post my model is null? loop index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that to get the model after post, we need to write the index in the razor view. My model has an entity from entity framework called Class, but that entity has en `ICollection<Student>` property navigation.

I mean, I need to exposure my items from Class entity, but the problem is that this one is ICollection and I don't have idea how to exposure the index.

Here is my razor view:

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.Models.Assignment.ShareAssignmentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShareAssignment";
}

<h2>Share Assignment: @Model.Assignment.Name</h2>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Classes.Length; i++)
{
<section>
    <h3>@Model.Classes[i].Name</h3>

    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Classes[i].Students.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBox(modelItem => Model.Classes[i].Students // what now?? [j])
    }
</section>
}
```

What can I do to get all my model after post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.Models.Assignment.ShareAssignmentViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShareAssignment";
}

<h2>Share Assignment: @Model.Assignment.Name</h2>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Classes.Length; i++)
{
   var studentsArray = Model.Classes[i].Students.ToArray();
<section>
    <h3>@Model.Classes[i].Name</h3>

    @for (int j = 0; j < studentsArray.Length; j++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="@(string.Format("Classes[{0}].Students[{1}]", i, j))" 
              value="@studentArray[j]" />
    }
</section>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to be using @Html.CheckBoxFor and not @Html.CheckBox?

In most cases, @Html.CheckBoxFor should do a good job rendering the markup needed to have the model populated automatically by the default model binder.  I have not tested this with your code, as I do not quite understand what is in the Model class.  However, if @Html.CheckBoxFor does not work, you can easily use a customized model binder.  One tutorial on this is here:

http://brendan.enrick.com/post/custom-model-binders-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: Yes sorry, it's CheckBoxFor